# Monotonically decreasing Approximation of a convex function

Tags: convex-analysis, approximation

I have a convex function of the form $f(x) = a + \frac{b}{x} + cx^2$ where $a, b,c$ are parameters. I need to find $a,b,c$ such that the resulting approximation function $f(x)$ is monotonic decreasing when x is in the range [0,50]. How can I find the $a,b,c$?

EDIT:
I started like this:

$dy/dx < 0 $

$ -b+ 2cx^3 < 0 $ in the domain [0,50]

I am not sure,how do I solve for b and c?
I am new to these kinds of problems and so a detailed explanation would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am assuming that "monotonically decreasing" is synonymous with "strictly decreasing".  If $f(x)$ is defined on an interval $D$, and $f'(x)<0$ throughout $D$, then $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing on the interval $D$.

Comment: If you expect people to put in the effort to answer a question, then it is polite to put in some effort yourself. For example, simply telling us where you got the problem from or explaining what you tried would be a big step forward! (For further feedback/help with asking questions, you can ask [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback).)